# WindowManager$BadTokenException even when checking isFinishing()

Tags: android, kotlin

Some people are getting this even tho I check if the activity is finishing or not. This app has a few million users and only 10 or so people are crashing. I am confused as to why.

```
private fun someFun(headerTitle: String, message: String) {
    if (isFinishing) return
    ComponentPopup.Builder(this)
       .setTitleText(headerTitle)
       .setMessageText(message)
       .setPositiveButtonText("Some text") 
       .setNegativeButtonText("Some text")
       .createPopup()
       .show()
}
```

ComponentPopup is just a custom component that extends Dialog.

Crashlytics says I get this exception at .show(). I don't call this function on a background thread either. Only on onBackPressed().

What gives? Why do I get this exception even though I check isFinishing?

Tried to finish the activity manually. Still wasn't able to produce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception. In my case the issue was I was passing the application context to the Builder instead of the Activity context. Hopefully, you are not doing so.

Just for testing, you may pass the context of your current Activity as YOUR_ACTIVITY.this instead of this.

This Issue happens when the user leave the activity before the diloag shown. So the dilaog didn't get the window of the specified Actvity to be show on.

You can generate the crash by calling the show of dialog and then instantly leave the activity.

Comment: I'm %100 sure I'm passing in the activity context. Since this is Kotlin "this" gives me the activity. As for the possible reason of this crash, as I said this application has a few million users so it's made as fail safe as possible but there's some extreme cases I'm missing and that's what I need help with. Such as, splitting the screen, which came to my mind today but I still wasn't able to produce this exception.

I've tried finishing the activity manually right before .show() or putting the app in the background or switching to another activity. None of them crashed the app.